# How to change sort order for  mail in thunderbird

Tags: configuration, thunderbird

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and Thunderbird came installed by default. I found that the mail in my inbox are sorted from oldest to newest and need to scroll to the bottom to find the latest mail.

Is there any setting to sort the newest mail at the top and the oldest to the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Thunderbird and just click on the **Date** column to reverse the sorting. A screenshot is given below:

[image]

Hope this will answer your query.